# can an NFT have supply more than one

Tags: tokens, nft, erc-1155

In ERC-1155 example [implementation](https://github.com/enjin/erc-1155/blob/master/contracts/ERC1155Mintable.sol) there is parameter to pass supply, so what if we pass supply more than 1, like 100 copies of an NFT, with same id, same metadata.

Does this violate definition of NFT? will it become FT when we pass supply more than 1?

Do we need to create as many NFTs as value in supply parameter with different token_ids?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, ERC-1155 isn't a "true" NFT. A "True" NFT is an ERC-721, where each token is truly unique. ERC-1155 is like a mix between ERC-721 and ERC-20 (NFTs and FTs).

Here's the high-level definition of ERC-1155 from [ethereum.org](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155):

> A standard interface for contracts that manage multiple token types. A single deployed contract may include any combination of fungible tokens, non-fungible tokens or other configurations (e.g. semi-fungible tokens).

Hence, ERC-1155 implements tokens that can be partially fungible.